# Iterating over 'table of' to produce ref cursor

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, associative-array, database-cursor

I have a number of old SP's which have output arguments of type 'table of', like this ...

```
TYPE tblSAM_DD_TEXT         IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE tblSAM_TYPE            IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


PROCEDURE Get_Associated_Unicorns(
    UNIID_IN IN ABC_UNICORNS.UNI_AUTOID%TYPE,
    ID_OUT OUT tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID,
    SAMDDTEXT_OUT OUT tblSAM_DD_TEXT,
    SAMTYPE_OUT OUT tblSAM_TYPE
);
```

... I'd like to adapt the existing processing so that the prototype of the sp's looked like this ...

```
TYPE t_cursor IS REF CURSOR ;
PROCEDURE Get_Associated_Unicorns(
    UNIID_IN IN ABC_UNICORNS.UNI_AUTOID%TYPE,
    v_cursor OUT t_cursor
);
```

... so that someone calling **Get_Associated_Unicorns** would have a ref cursor to consume rather than three 'table of' objects.

Using Oracle 10g PL/SQL how can I adapt the existing SP's so that I iterate over the 'table of' objects to populate a ref cursor which is then the sole output argument ?

*(the three 'table of' arguments are always of the same length)*.

Comment: Are the three table type variables being populated within the get_associated_unicorns procedure? If so, are they populated via SQL select statements?

Answer (score 1):

If you first create 3 types in your database

```
CREATE TYPE tblSAM_DD_TEXT         IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
CREATE TYPE tblSAM_TYPE            IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
CREATE TYPE tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32);
```

You can then refer to them in a procedure

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_Associated_Unicorns 
                                 ( p_tblSAM_DD_TEXT      IN  tblSAM_DD_TEXT
                                  ,p_tblSAM_TYPE         IN  tblSAM_TYPE
                                  ,p_tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID IN  tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID
                                  ,pc_refcursor          OUT sys_refcursor)
BEGIN

OPEN pc_refcursor FOR
SELECT tblSAM_DD_TEXT SAM_DD_TEXT
      ,tblSAM_TYPE    SAM_TYPE
      ,tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID CONSOLIDATED_ID
FROM   (SELECT column_value tblSAM_DD_TEXT
              ,rownum       r1
        FROM   TABLE(p_tblSAM_DD_TEXT))
      ,(SELECT column_value tblSAM_TYPE
              ,rownum       r2
        FROM   TABLE(p_tblSAM_TYPE))
      ,(SELECT column_value tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID
              ,rownum       r3
        FROM   TABLE(p_tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID))
WHERE  r1 = r2
AND    r2 = r3;


END;
```

Comment: I assume that the OP didn't want to pass the three tables in to the Proc, if they are already being populated within it then they can be iterated through via the method you suggest without having them in the procedure's signature. (if ideed they have to be iterated through and the ref_cursor cannot just be populated directly).

Comment: @Ollie Possibly southof40 wasn't thinking of passing the 3 tables into a separate procedure, but to maximise reusability and reduce coupling I think it would be best to do the conversion to a ref cursor in a separate procedure such as the above.

Comment: good point (+1), it would reduce the coupling with the original procedure. Looking at the whole issue the OP has though (and making a few...ahem...assumptions) it might be better all round if they didn't populate the three tables in the first place (if possible) and simply populate the ref_cursor directly.